# Mysql 5.5 Query Optimisation

Tags: mysql, optimization

Struggling to get a mysql 5.5 query working efficiently with existing indexes, which to my limited knowledge and experience should be enough to do the job. The query executes fast enough at present but I'd rather get this right before scaling up.

Table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (  
  taskid INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  clientid INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  
  taskdata CHAR(40) NOT NULL,  
  tasktype SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  
  clientstaskref CHAR(40) NOT NULL,  
  deadline DATETIME NOT NULL,  
  canbeongoing BIT(1) NOT NULL,  
  isunderway BIT(1) NOT NULL,  
  checkenabled BIT(1) NOT NULL,  
  lastupdated DATETIME NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (taskid),  
  UNIQUE KEY clientstaskref (clientstaskref),  
  UNIQUE KEY checkenabled (checkenabled,clientid,taskid),  
  KEY deadline (deadline),  
  KEY lastupdated (lastupdated),  
  KEY isunderway (isunderway),  
  KEY taskdata (taskdata),  
  KEY tasktype (tasktype),  
  KEY clientid (clientid,tasktype)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE tasktypes (  
  typeid SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  subtypeid SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  
  typedesc CHAR(40) NOT NULL,  
  rectype CHAR(40) NOT NULL,  
  checkenabled BIT(1) NOT NULL,  
  firstadded DATETIME NOT NULL,  
  lastupdated DATETIME NOT NULL,  
  isaccountable BIT(1) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (typeid),  
  UNIQUE KEY checkenabled (checkenabled,subtypeid,typedesc),  
  UNIQUE KEY typeid (typeid,typedesc),  
  UNIQUE KEY subtypeid (subtypeid,typedesc),  
  KEY typedesc (typedesc)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The rogue query:

```
SELECT a.taskid, a.taskdata, b.typedesc, a.deadline, a.checkenabled  
FROM tasks AS a, tasktypes AS b  
WHERE a.clientid = 220  
AND a.tasktype = b.typeid  
ORDER BY b.typedesc
```

Explain output:

```
id  select_type  table  type    possible_keys      key       key_len  ref                 rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE       a      ref     tasktype,clientid  clientid  4        const               56    Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE       b      eq_ref  PRIMARY,typeid     PRIMARY   2        testing.a.tasktype  1
```

Obviously I'd like to get rid of the Using temporary; Using filesort!

Apologies if this duplicates an existing question but there's a hell of a lot of slightly similar questions and it looks like it'd take weeks to identify one that offers a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unpanic**

No, it is not obvious that you should get rid of "Using temporary; Using filesort".  They are the fastest way to get the query performed.

Let's dissect the query...

You are `JOINing` two tables.  But you are filtering on one (`a.clientid`) yet sorting on the other (`b.typedesc`).  The only way to avoid the tmp+filesort is to have a single index that covers all of the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses.  This is impossible.

So, instead, the optimizer decides to 'filter' on `a.clientid` first, hoping to get the number of interesting rows down to an estimate of 56.  Then it `JOINs` to the other table in an optimal way (`eq_ref..PRIMARY`).  Finally it sorts the ~56 rows.

Don't despair.  "Using temporary; Using filesort" are misnomers.  If all goes well, the "temp" will be an in-RAM `MEMORY` table, and the "filesort" won't touch any "file", but simply do a qsort of the Memory table.

**Some other tips**...

- Don't use `CHAR(..)` unless the column is really fixed length.  `VARCHAR(..)` is probably better.
- Don't index flags (eg, `isunderway`), such an index is almost never used.
- Please change to the `JOIN...ON...` syntax.
- Redundancy:  `PRIMARY KEY (typeid)` and `UNIQUE KEY typeid (typeid,typedesc)`:
  A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE KEY`.  Adding the second column to the unique key does not make it "more unique" or anything else useful.  InnoDB tables cluster around the PK, so having another index starting with the PK is almost always a waste.  DROP that UNIQUE key.

Comment: Many thanks for the useful answer! A few tutorials I've used seem to consider temporary/filesort as the work of the devil, but thinking about it the filter on a.clientid is always going to bring the number of rows down to under 150 ish at most, so there's never going to be a lot of data to sort anyway. The redundant key was added in desperate experimentation!